# How to fix "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexptected token L in JSON at position 1"

Tags: javascript, c#, android, json, jsonparser

I have `JavaScript` function where a `JSON` parser is used:

```
function myFunction(jobj) {   
  jobj = JSON.parse(jobj);
  console.log("jobj: ", jobj);
}
```

I have 2 apps (one Visual Studio C# app and one Android Studio app) with a WebView "myWebView" where I call the JavaScript function "myFunction":

**Code in C#**

```
JObject jobj = new JObject();
jobj.Add("id", "testId");
jobj.Add("value", "1234");
String json = jobj.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, null);
String[]jsonArray = new String[] { json  };
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () => await myWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("myFunction", jsonArray));
```

**Code in Android:**

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("id", "testId");
jsonObj.put("value", "1234");
String json = jsonObj.toString();
String[]jsonArray = new String[] { json  };                                          
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction('" + jsonArray + "')");
```

In C# it's working fine.

But in Android when I do the parse I get the error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexptected token L in JSON at position 1

Thanks, best regards Phil

Comment: show your json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android you're using Java. When you use the concatenation operator in Java, the operand is turned into a string. However, you are concatenating `jsonArray`, which is an array — and arrays' string representation is cryptic. For example, `new String[] { "foo", "bar" };` stringifies as `"[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55"`, *not* `["foo", "bar"]` as it would in most sensible languages. You might replace `jsonArray` there with

```
"[" + String.join(", ", jsonArray) + "]"
```

Comment: thanks for the info. Now I use the string and not the String[] for the function:
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction('" + json + "')");
this is working for me